# I am trying to download all pdf files in google drive but failing to save each pdf located in google drive

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api

I am supposed to download all the pdf documents from google drive, but when i run the code the same pdf file will download multiple times with different names,for example if i have 3 pdf documents in drive, say pdf1, pdf2, pdf3
When i try to download ,it will download pdf1 and then replace with pdf2 and again replace with pdf3 , pdf3 is downloading thrice and saving with different names.

```
public static void Dwfiles(DriveService service)
    {

        // Define parameters of request.
        FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
        listRequest.MaxResults = 100;

        // List files.
        IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute()
            .Items;

        Console.WriteLine("Files:");
        if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                //var request = service.Files.Get(file.Id);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", file.Title, file.Id);
                //Debug.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", file.Title, file.Id);
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------");



                    var request = service.Files.Get(file.Id);

                    using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                    {
                        // Add a handler which will be notified on progress changes.
                        // It will notify on each chunk download and when the
                        // download is completed or failed.
                        request.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged +=
                            (IDownloadProgress progress) =>
                            {
                                switch (progress.Status)
                                {
                                    case DownloadStatus.Downloading:
                                        {
                                            Console.WriteLine(progress.BytesDownloaded);
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    case DownloadStatus.Completed:
                                        {
                                            Console.WriteLine("Download complete.");
                                            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------");
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    case DownloadStatus.Failed:
                                        {
                                            Console.WriteLine("Download failed.");
                                            break;
                                        }
                                }
                            };
                             request.Download(stream);
                            for (int a = 0; a < files.Count; a++)
                            {

                        var filepath = @"I:\testing\downloaded11 ";
                                    var filepath2 = filepath + (a + 1) + ".pdf";
                                    using (var filestream = new FileStream(filepath2, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                                    {
                                        filestream.Write(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, stream.GetBuffer().Length);

                                    }

                            }

                    }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have a think about the clause starting

```
for (int a = 0; a < files.Count; a++)
```

You're already inside a foreach loop of all the files:

```
foreach (var file in files)
```

**EDIT**

If there are ten files on the Google drive, you're saving each one ten times, each overwriting the ten copies of the previous file you downloaded.

Instead of

```
for (int a = 0; a < files.Count; a++)
{
    var filepath = @"I:\testing\downloaded11 "
    var filepath2 = filepath + (a + 1) + ".pdf";

    using (var filestream = new FileStream(filepath2, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        filestream.Write(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, stream.GetBuffer().Length);
    }
}
```

try just

```
var filepath = @"I:\testing\downloaded11\" + file.OriginalFilename;
using (var filestream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        filestream.Write(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, stream.GetBuffer().Length);
    }
```

Comment: Even i thought about it.  But how do i increment this

var filepath2 = filepath + (a + 1) + &quot;.pdf&quot;;

@barrik

Comment: No problem! Mark it as the answer when you get a moment!